# Retrieve filename startwith character using package.xml

Tags: package

I know that we can retrieve all file name using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
       <name>ApexClass</name>
 </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

Is there any way we can retrieve file start or contain with character example 'MyClass__' using package.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use wildcards to find partial file matches with package.xml.

Take a look at the [Tquila package.xml builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/), it might make the process of creating your project contents a little easier.

Comment: thanks.. i am trying it.It is very slow...is it normal?

Comment: It can take a few mintues, especially if you have a very large project.

Comment: but it does not ask me what project but it just ask to login either  sandbox or production.if it take all component from the org sandbox it will be forever lol.

Comment: On the Oauth page your username is displayed in the top right of the corner, this will tell you which environment it is authenticating into. Usually I use a different browser for each environment